# Where to download Google Drive API v3 library files from?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-drive-api

I recently downloaded objective C client library of google drive api from here https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client

Can anyone tell me as to which version does this client library belongs to ? I am not able to find this detail anywhere.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the library you mentioned uses Google Drive API v3: https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/blob/6b3410fce1dfc595dca438542c91ea44d6a1c42e/Source/Services/Drive/Generated/GTLDriveAbout.h#L23

`// NOTE: This file is generated from Google APIs Discovery Service.
// Service:
//   Drive API (drive/v3)
// Description:
//   The API to interact with Drive.`